# Increasingly Long Runtime for Macro

Tags: optimization, vba, excel

My code works, but the problem is that it is taking an increasingly long time to run, with the time required to complete calculations increasing every time I use the macro. I've tried a variety of variations and modifications with the syntax, but as I'm pretty new to VBA, I haven't made a whole lot of progress.

Here's the code I'm running (Note, it is running as a subset, and `ScreenUpdate = False`):

```
Public Sub deleteRows()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Set the range of interest, no need to include the entire data range
            With .Range("B2:F" & lastRow)
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=0.000", Operator:=xlFilterValues
                .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=0.000", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With
        .Range("B1:F" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End With
    MsgBox Format(Time - start, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

This code basically removes zero-valued results from the data by deleting an entire row. Initially, it ran in about 12 seconds, but that soon became 55 second, which has progressed into increasing long runtimes, with a 'fast' now being in the 5 minuet range. Below is a spreadsheet with the recorded runtimes and corresponding changes made:

> ```
> Runtime   Changes
> 6:30  None
> 7:50  None
> 5:37  Manually stepped through code
> 7:45  Run with .cells instead of .range("B1:B" & lastRow)
> 5:21  Run with .Range(B:B)  instead of .range("B1:B" & lastRow)
> 9:20  Run with application.calculation disabled/enabled, range unchanged
> 5:35  Run with application.enableEvents disabled/enabled, range unchanged
> 11:08 Run with application.enableEvents disabled/enabled, Range(B:B)
> 5:12  None
> 7:57  Run with Alternative code (old code)
> 5:45  Range changed to .Range(cells(2,2), Cells(lastRow,2)
> 10:25 Range changed to .Range(cells(2,2), Cells(lastRow,2), Application.Calculation Disabled/enabled
> 5:34  Range set to rngB  for .delete portion (range assigned to variable)
> 9:59  Range set as rng("B1:F" & lastRow)
> 5:58  Changed system settings for Excel to "High Priority", code reverted to original
> 9:41  Rerun of old code for comparison
> 9:26  Reun with change in old code criteria to "0.000"
> 0:10  Moved SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
> 5:15  Rerun  SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
> 11:31 Rerun  SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
> 11:38 Excel restart; Rerun  SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
> 5:18  Excel restart; Rerun  SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
> 6:49  Removed 2nd with 'loop'; all data put into first with statement
> ```

I did some research online, and it looks like this might be a known issue with Excel when working with large datasets, and as mine is ~51k rows, I can see how this might be the case.

> ...A macro that required several seconds to complete in an earlier version of Excel may require several minutes to complete in a later version of Excel. Alternatively, if you run a macro a second time, the macro may take twice as long to run as it did the first time.

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199505)

Is there any way to make this run faster, like it initially did? Why is this happening?

Comment: This might be better suited on Stack Overflow. If your problem is due to external factors, reviewing the code won't change much about your situation.

Comment: @ Pimgd I intially posted this question on StackOverflow, but I was recommended to this part of the forum. What kind of external factors would affect the runtime?

Comment: The same factors you mentioned! Basically, I'm saying that here we'll review the code, but if you think the problem is related to some bug in excel you might be better off not asking here. If you wish to see if the code itself can be optimized, then let me welcome you to Code Review!

Comment: Well thanks! Good to be here. I was hoping to find some advice regarding the EntireRow.Delete method in particular, as that is taking the majority of the runtime; i.e. find alterntive solutions that would have the same result, but potentially avoid the issues I've been having.

Comment: Does your spreadsheet have many formulas?

Comment: [Link to the crosspost](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25162118/3198973).

Comment: All of my data at this point in the code is static. Just values, no formulas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't solve the long run times of your code if the issue is the `EntireRow.Delete` method.  I assume you still want those rows deleted and stackoverflow would be the place to get a workaround or solution.

That being said your code should be reviewed.

---

> ```
> Rows("1:1").Select
> Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
> ```

Never use `Select` unless you are making some macro to find a range for the user. Use `Rows("1:1").Insert ...`.  Making these concatenations should be priority #1 after recording a macro.  Also you are not declaring the parent of `Rows`.  `ActiveSheet` is implicitly the parent but `Rows` is already nested in a `With` statment.  Just put the period `.Rows("1:1")...` to make it explicit.

---

> ```
> With ActiveSheet
> ```

As you said, this is being called as a sub function.  If your project grows to include more sheets, assuming ActiveSheet is the sheet you want to manipulate won't be safe.  Any Sub not meant to be an outermost Sub should not use `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveBook`, `ActiveCell`, or `Selection`.  Sheets, books, and ranges should be passed as an argument.

---

This variable isn't being used. Delete it.

> ```
> Dim rng As Range
> ```

---

You get the last row by going to the bottom of the sheet and iterating up until you find the bottom of your data.

> ```
> lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
> ```

Instead get the bottom of the range containing data:

```
lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

---

Now there is the general steps that your macro takes.  It operates like user interaction, which is usually not the best way to approach it.  The steps you take:

- AutoFilter the range

  - only rows with columns "C" and "F" are visible
- Delete all visible rows in the range

It makes perfect sense in a user interface side but from a programming side is unnecessarily indirect.  Rows to delete are marked by remaining visible and then deleted.  What if something else has marked rows as invisible?  I would suggest iterating over all rows in the range and deleting those that should be.

```
Public Sub DeleteRows()
    ' ActiveSheet or Range("B2:F" & lastRow) should be passed
    Dim sheet as Worksheet
    set sheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim table as Range        
    set table = sheet.Range("B2:F" & lastRow)

    Dim l as Long
    For l = lastRow to 1 step -1

        If ShouldBeDeleted(table.rows(l)) Then 

            table.rows(l).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp

        End If

    Next l

    ' These should be in the outside Sub
    sheet.Range("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    MsgBox Format(Time - start, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
Function ShouldBeDeleted(row_range as Range) as Boolean

    ShouldBeDeleted = (row_range.cells(1, 2) = 0 And row_range.cells(1, 5) = 0)

End Function
```

Pulling bits out like `ShouldBeDeleted` might seem verbose but there is a better name for it.  There is something special about those rows, and I would rename the function `IsX` where X describes what those rows are.  Also, columns "C" and "F" seem to be special for your worksheet.  If they are so, declare them as constants

```
Const IMPORTANT_COL_1 As String = "C"
Const IMPORTANT_COL_2 As String = "F"
```

### Sorting Optimizations

If sorting the rows of the table is allowed and 0 is the minimum then you could sort the table and only iterate over the rows that you need to delete.

```
Public Sub DeleteRows(table as Range)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = table.Rows.Count

    With table.Parent.Sort

        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add key:=table.Range(IMPORTANT_COL_1 & ":" & IMPORTANT_COL_1)
        .SortFields.Add key:=table.Range(IMPORTANT_COL_2 & ":" & IMPORTANT_COL_2)
        .SetRange table
        .Apply

    End With

    Dim botRow as Long
    botRow = 1

    While ShouldBeDeleted(table.rows(botRow))
        botRow = botRow + 1
    Wend

    table.range("1:" & botRow).Delete shift:=xlUP

End Sub
```

Comment: You make a good point, but since OP's main concern is performance, I'm not sure iterating over rows to delete them is a good idea. Otherwise a great review.

Comment: Yes I can't quite reproduce his performance issue.  At 5x10^4 rows I consistently get 6-7 seconds.

Comment: @ptwales Thanks for all the advice! I'm trying to learn VBA, so I've been using the "Record Macro" option a lot, and then going back and cleaning up the code, which would explain my organization style. Thankfully, David Zemens was able to provide an alternate solution on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Redshift Good to hear a solution.  If the rows can be rearranged and 0 is the minimum I would suggest sorting the data by "E" and "F" or the "=E+F" instead of using AutoFilter. And then a Do While to find the length of the range.  However Excels sorting commands are rather verbose.